# How to automatically update a pivot table filter to all items in a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: filter, spreadsheet

I have a [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PGbsMj3oZxszXsw-j4_Z6U9nG0_uFgAdAbiWn610nnM/edit?usp=sharing). The sheet SourceData contains data which is referenced by a pivot table (Sheet PT1). The chart uses the pivot table.

When a new date is entered into SourceData, such as **2015 - 09 Sep** I would like the filter in PT1 to include this new data/row.

If you look at the link you will see the 2015 - 09 Sep is not in the chart because the filter is only set to 33 items, not all items. The filter was set to all items but when I add a new row to SourceData it does not include the new data.